# Transparent texture + roughness

Tags: materials, transparency, roughness

I have a window texture with alpha channel. Texture is applied to whole plane, no additional geometry.

I want texture in part where it has alfa value to be transparent, but at the same time has reflection through roughness.

How to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). That's what the *Transmission* slider does (glass). It's transparent, but still shows reflections from grazing angles.

Comment: @JachymMichal, thanks that works